# Java 8 streams : For Each

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Can you help me code the following using the  Java 8 stream API?

```
SuperUser superUser = db.getSuperUser;
for (final Client client : superUser) {
    if (cartData.getClient().equals(client.getUid())) {
        client.setIsSelected(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, I'd like to add that calling `cartData.getClient()` each time in the loop is sub-optimal instead cache it before the start of the loop as seen below:

```
T tempClient = cartData.getClient();  // where T is the type returned by getClient()
```

Then you can do:

```
  superUser.stream()  // or Arrays.steam(superUser) if superUser is an array
           .filter(c -> tempClient.equals(c.getUid()))
           .findFirst()
           .ifPresent(client -> client.setIsSelected(true));
```

or:

```
superUser.stream() // or Arrays.steam(superUser) if superUser is an array
         .filter(c -> tempClient.equals(c.getUid()))
         .limit(1)
         .forEach(client -> client.setIsSelected(true));
```

Comment: @Rann Lifshitz Thanks for the edit but changing it from "instead cache it ..." to "instead of caching it..." contradicts with my intention. Currently, with your edit, it seems as if the OP is _already_ caching the reference to `cartData.getClient();` before the loop which is not the case.  will revert that specific part and leave the subsequent change :)

Comment: Sure thing buddy, sorry for the mistake. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

How to code this using Java 8 stream:

```
SuperUser superUser = db.getSuperUser;
for (final Client client : superUser) { 
   if (cartData.getClient().equals(client.getUid())) {
      client.setIsSelected(true); 
      break; 
    }
}
```

For-each does not seem like the proper tool for this job.
You could try:

```
superUser.stream()
         .filter(c -> cartData.getClient().equals(c.getUid()))
         .findFirst().ifPresent(c -> c.setIsSelected(true));
```